# kivy: horizontal ListView

Tags: android, python, layout, kivy

Is there posibility to create in Kivy framework horizontal ListView?

All examples shows how to create a list of elements with vertical orientation, but i need to arrange them horizontally with horizontal scrollbar.

Defaults:

```
:                   :
|                   |
+-------------------+  ^
|                   |  ^
|     Element 5     |  ^
|                   |  |
+-------------------+  |
|                   |  |
|     Element 6     |  |
|                   |  |
+-------------------+  |
|                   |  |
|     Element 7     |  |
|                   |  v
+-------------------+  v
|                   |  v
:                   :
```

I would like to:

```
... --+-----------+-----------+-----------+---- ...
      |           |           |           |
      | Element 5 | Element 6 | Element 7 |
      |           |           |           |
... --+-----------+-----------+-----------+---- ...

   <<<---------------------------------------->>>
```

Comment: I guess you could in principle rotate the ListView (i.e. in a Scatter), then populate it with widgets whose contents have the opposite rotation. That would give the desired behaviour.

Comment: The problem would be that the text would also rotate. You could rotate again each text. No real need for Scatter which is meant for rotating, scaling and translating with gestures. Instead, you could use the `Rotate` instruction of the canvas. I recently wrote a post about using [Rotate](http://robertour.com/2013/08/08/simple-rotations-of-images-in-kivy/). Anyway, using `Scatter` or `Rotate` seems way too complicated to achieve something that should be simple.

Answer (score 1):

Orientation is hard-coded. If you look at https://github.com/kivy/kivy/blob/master/kivy/uix/listview.py you will find:

```
Builder.load_string('''
<ListView>:
    container: container
    ScrollView:
        pos: root.pos
        on_scroll_y: root._scroll(args[1])
        do_scroll_x: False
        GridLayout:
            cols: 1
            id: container
            size_hint_y: None
''')
```

I copied this file into project directory and replaced this with:

```
Builder.load_string('''
<ListView>:
    container: container
    ScrollView:
        pos: root.pos
        on_scroll_y: root._scroll(args[1])
        do_scroll_x: False
        GridLayout:
            rows: 1
            id: container
            size_hint_y: None
''')
```

And with this test code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from listview import ListView
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout


class MainView(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        kwargs['cols'] = 2
        super(MainView, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        list_view = ListView(item_strings=[str(index) for index in range(100)])

        self.add_widget(list_view)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    from kivy.base import runTouchApp
    runTouchApp(MainView(width=800))
```

I managed to get horizontal list. However, it broke the scrolling. Looks like you have to alter this configuration more and modify scrolling method as well to achieve desired result.